# Error: KrigingModelOrdinary not defined in python

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, kriging

Here is the code:

```
rasterKrig = "run{}_Krig_{}".format(counter, field)
outKrig = arcpy.sa.Kriging(Stations2010o3Data__2_, field, KrigingModelOrdinary, {2})
outKrig.save(rasterKrig)
arcpy.env.extent = tempEnvironment0
```

I am getting a runback error:

> KrigingModelOrdinary not defined in python

How and where do I define the KrigingModelOrdinary?

Answer (score 4):

[KrigingModelOrdinary](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005m00000054000000) is another function in the `arcpy.sa` module. If you want to use it as a variable, it needs to be defined earlier in your code. The Arc help page walks through the necessary inputs/usage; the following is a snippet based on their example.

```
# Create KrigingModelOrdinary Object
lagSize = 70000
majorRange = 250000
partialSill = 180000
nugget = 34000
kModelOrdinary = arcpy.sa.KrigingModelOrdinary("CIRCULAR", lagSize, majorRange,
                                               partialSill, nugget)

# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Execute Kriging
outKrigingOrd2 = arcpy.sa.Kriging(inPointFeature, "ELEVATION", kModelOrdinary, 2000,
                                  RadiusFixed(200000, 10), outVarRaster)
```

Comment: line 53, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 2405, in Kriging
    out_variance_prediction_raster)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 47, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 2397, in wrapper
    out_variance_prediction_raster)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 484, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))

Comment: No idea. I've never used the function myself. Sorry :(

Comment: It has something to do with how I am saving my results from the Kriging, just not sure how to change it